# already installed but ModuleNotFoundError: No module named matplotlib'

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install matplotlib with Anaconda using Pycharm and it says there is no module even though I have just installed it, then uninstalled and reinstalled it again.

I entered this in the terminal:

`conda install matplotlib`

Then testing that I have in fact installed it, I put this into the terminal with the following result:

```
conda install matplotlib
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

I then proceed to the console to type:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

With the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

This makes no sense to me whatsoever. This also happens when trying to import `geojson` as well. Could someone explain?

Comment: Did you manage to fix that? If so, how